# DataTables gave me this error (headerCells[i].style.width = column.sWidthOrig)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

DataTable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Please any idea??

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
>       at _fnCalculateColumnWidths (jquery_datatables.self-a9908e5a65de4eeb0522babd326c527638c2ff12f0b4c3f61deb76b1dc27e25d.js?body=1:4166)

[image]

Comment: you're looping i from 0 to visibleColumns.length ... is `headerCells.length` <= `visibleColumns.length` ? if not, then you have a problem

Comment: Seems like you found where it gets stucked in DataTables .js file... But that is certainly due to your code. You should post it.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick solution, set autoWidth as false

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
            'destroy': true,
            "autoWidth": false,
```